# Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 - Slower in Ubuntu than in Windows

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros, firmware

I have had two different machines now using the same WiFi chip, the Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174. When I used it via 802.11n (2.4 GHz) connection, it tended to entirely lose its connection from time to time, after switching to 802.11ac (5 GHz) the connection became more stable, but still rather slow. There aren't many networks around, so interference is no issue. Indeed, when booted to Windows 10, the net connection speed is around 500 MBit/s, whereas in Ubuntu 16.04 as well as Linux Mint 18.1 the data rate drops to around 80 MBit/s.

Additionally, the router/AP shows the machine being connected with a connection speed in the 600-800 MBit/s range, depending on exact positioning, but independent of the OS used.

I have already cleared out the usual suspects: `linux-firmware` is installed and up to date, I have already tried the `firmware-4.bin` and `board-2.bin` files from https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0,

`lspci -knn | grep Net A2` returns:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3044]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

I have already set my WiFi card to favor IPv4 over IPv6 as pointed out here: [Very slow internet connection on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764387/very-slow-internet-connection-on-ubuntu-16-04), but to no avail. I also tried the `board-2.bin` and `firmware-4.bin` files from the other answer in that post, also without success.

What puzzles me so much is that it does seem to work flawlessly, but the transfer rates are no match at all for those in the Windows world.