# Upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04, slow ethernet connection

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

I have upgraded from 14.04 about a week ago and now my internet connection is slow. It is only slow on this computer and I cannot figure what is going wrong.

From my searching I have found that it could be that IPv6 is slowing down my connection. Issuing the command `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` reports `1` and this should mean that IPv6 is disable but the problem persists. Even after a reboot.

Any ideas? If this can't be worked out I may just go back to 14.04.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here are the results from speedtest.net on the Ubuntu 16.04 computer: `Ping: 9ms, Download 8.99 Mbps, UPLOAD
0.96 Mbps.` These numbers are not far from what I'm paying for. Maybe the problem is different; although I experience the same slow speeds in both firefox and google chrome.

Anyway, here are the results from the various network commands:

```
ifconfig -a

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:60:6e:82:a1:50  
      inet addr:192.168.0.108  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:301143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:169836 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:393327698 (393.3 MB)  TX bytes:18792937 (18.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:104670 (104.6 KB)  TX bytes:104670 (104.6 KB)
```

Next.

```
lspci | grep Eth

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
```

Next again.

```
lshw
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: enp2s0
                version: 09
                serial: 08:60:6e:82:a1:50
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 ip=192.168.0.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:26 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fafff000-faffffff memory:faff8000-faffbfff
```

Lastly, `lsmod | grep driver_name_in_lshw` does not display anything.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not to doubt your analysis but to take the subjectivity out of what's "slow", do a speed test

```
http://speedtest.net
```

Assuming your ethernet is indeed running slow, find out if the NIC is generating errors, dropped packets and so on

```
ifconfig -a
```

Check to see if the correct driver is installed

`lspci | grep Eth` - Described the Eth hardware

`lshw` - scroll down to the Eth HW section and see what driver is installed

```
lsmod | grep driver_name_in_lshw
```

IPv6 should not be a factor unless there is a bug in 16.06

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant 16.04 in the title, sorry about that. The reason I say that IPv4 could be slowing my connection is because of these links: https://askubuntu.com/questions/764387/very-slow-internet-connection-on-ubuntu-16-04 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsingSlowIPv6IPv4 I'll Edit my OP comment with outputs to those commands.

Comment: Off the top I think the IPv6 thing could be a red herring.  The "bug" only seems to effect DNS lookups which will not be a factor if you run the speedtest I mentioned in my answer.  If speedtest shows that your NIC is operating at about the maximum speed for the Internet connection you have, then taking a look at how long DNS lookups take might make sense.  I've been running 16.04 on several machines for a very long time and the e-net speed is rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

You have one, or both, of a couple of problems...

- you're only connecting at 100mbit when your interface can do 1gbit. Check/replace your ethernet cable with a cat5 or better cable, or a gigabit switch/hub/router with a hosed port... a power off/on may fix problems with these.
- the r8169 driver is buggy. Replace it with r8168-dkms.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```